# How to Read Certain Lines After Some Text in a File in Shell Script

Tags: sql, bash, shell, awk

I Have SQL file, i need to get the SQL Query from the Specific SQL Query(i.e.  SQL Query passed by the user) to the end of the SQL File.

Lets have an Example:

Below is the SQL file:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Thomas', 'Tom B. James', 'Skagen 22', 'Stavanger', '4007', 'Norway');

Update Customers set CustomerName = 'ABC' where PostalCode = '4006'

Delete from Customers where PostalCode = '4007'

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Rose', 'Tom B. Smith', 'Skagen 23', 'Stavanger', '4008', 'Norway');

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Jim', 'Tom B. Jonny', 'Skagen 24', 'Stavanger', '4009', 'Norway');
```

Here user passess the query `Update Customers set CustomerName = 'ABC' where PostalCode = '4006'` and i am storing the SQL Query which is passed by the user in the variable `$sql`

Now i need to get Output as below

```
Update Customers set CustomerName = 'ABC' where PostalCode = '4006'

Delete from Customers where PostalCode = '4007'

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Rose', 'Tom B. Smith', 'Skagen 23', 'Stavanger', '4008', 'Norway');

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Jim', 'Tom B. Jonny', 'Skagen 24', 'Stavanger', '4009', 'Norway');
```

To get the above output i am using below code

```
awk -v var="$sql" '$0 == "var" {i=1;next};i && i++' test.sql
```

Here i am storing the sql variable content in the var variable and searching for the particular SQL Query in the file and after getting the particular SQL Query(which is passed by the user) i am printing the SQL Query from the SQL Query which user has passed to End of the file.

One More Example :

If the user passes `INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country) VALUES ('Rose', 'Tom B. Smith', 'Skagen 23', 'Stavanger', '4008', 'Norway');` I should get the below output

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Rose', 'Tom B. Smith', 'Skagen 23', 'Stavanger', '4008', 'Norway');

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Jim', 'Tom B. Jonny', 'Skagen 24', 'Stavanger', '4009', 'Norway');
```

I am not getting the output.

Can anyone help me out with the above issue. It will he very helpful.

**Note: My SQL Query is having all DML statements also my one SQL query is not a single line query. It will occupy more than 4-5 lines. Example purpose i have used Single line Query here.**

Can anyone help me out with the generic method so that it will be useful for all the SQL Query present in the file?

Comment: Changing or adding new requirements to question later on always creates confusions, your samples NEVER said they had anything else apart from INSERT and VALUE lines, we could never come to know about it(since nothing there like that in shown samples). Please do mention all your conditions in very first/base question itself. Please do add samples of DML etc statements you want to catch for your Input_file in your question with CODE TAGS.

Comment: There's a LOT of text in the above question. If you can reduce it to a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and what you've tried so far along with a brief explanation of your requirements then you'll have a lot more people willing/able to invest the greatly reduced time trying to understand your question so they can help you. Don't expect anyone to understand what `My SQL Query is having all DML statements` or anything else domain-specific means, just describe your problem in terms of strings in rows and columns and make sure your example covers your needs.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
##Creating shell variables named insert and value here before passing them to awk code.
insert="INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)"
value="VALUES ('Rose', 'Tom B. Smith', 'Skagen 23', 'Stavanger', '4008', 'Norway');"

##Starting awk code from here and passing shell variables to it.
awk -v insert="$insert" -v value="$value" '
/^INSERT/ && foundInsertcouple{
  print
  next
}
/^VALUES/ && foundInsertcouple{
  print
  foundInsertcouple=""
  next
}
/^INSERT/ && $0==insert{
  foundInsert=1
  val=$0
  next
}
/^VALUES/ && foundInsert && $0==value{
  print val ORS $0
  val=foundInsert=""
  foundInsertcouple=1
  next
}'  Input_file
```

Comment: This is working only for the above query which I have posted. My SQL file is not only having insert statements it is also having DML commands. Can I get a generic method so that i can store any SQL query in the variable and pass the variable in awk command. 

I will be very helpful.

Comment: @Shreyas, Sure, please check my edited solution now, we need 2 variables here which are getting passed to awk code and then doing the operation in it.

Comment: Yea, i saw.

I think it will work only for Insert not for other DML statements.
Is there any way to store entire query in a single variable.
It will be very helpful.

Comment: @Shreyas, Sorry but your question never said that :(  so I was not sure what else could come. Please do edit your question with clear samples and let me know then here.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the questions with clear samples.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL: `select id, firstname, lastname from authors`

If one provided: `Firstname: evil'ex` and `Lastname: Newman`

the query string becomes:

```
select id, firstname, lastname from authors where firstname = 'evil'ex' and lastname ='newman'
```

which the database attempts to run as:

> Incorrect syntax near il' as the database tried to execute evil.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the correct answer

```sh
file='read_file.txt'  
  
i=1  
while read line; do  
  
#Reading each line  
echo "Line No. $i : $line"  
i=$((i+1))  
done < $file
```

Comment: If you copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net it'll tell you about some of the issues and see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for others.